# PHP JsonSerializable nested object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, nested

I have a curious problem and I can't find how to resolve it.
I'm using the JsonSerializable interface in PHP to create a JSON to return. In one object I'm using, I have a variable that is an array of objects. It's working when the array contain only one object but when there is several I get an empty array. I don't understand. Here it's the code :

```
class SessionDate implements JsonSerializable {

    private $_players;

    public function getPlayers() { return $this->_players; }
    public function setPlayers($players) {
        $this->_players = $players;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return [
            'players' => $this->getPlayers() // This is an array of player
        ];
    }

}

class Player implements JsonSerializable {

    private $_id;
    private $_name;

    public function getId() { return $this->_id; }
    public function setId($id) { $this->_id = $id; }

    public function getName() { return $this->_name; }
    public function setName($name) { $this->_name = $name; }

    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return [
            'id' => $this->getId(),
            'name' => $this->getName()
        ];
    }

}
```

And this is how I get the list of players :

```
        $q = $this->_db->prepare('the query');

        $q->execute();
        $players = [];
        while ($data = $q->fetch()) {
            $sessionPlayer = constructPlayer($data);
            $players[] = $sessionPlayer;
        }

        return $players;
```

What am I doing wrong ? And why is it working when there is one player and not with more ??

Thanks.

** EDIT **

I call the php action with $.ajax and it appears that when there is more than one player, the $.ajax response goes through error. So maybe it's because the JSON is not formatted well...

Comment: What's `constructPlayer`?

Comment: It's just a series of setting data to the object player. This is working because where there is only one I get all the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your $players Object to json_encode with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

```
echo json_encode($players, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

> JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE - Do not convert Unicode charactors to escape sequences (\uXXX) **Added in PHP 5.4**